# Hadoop mapreduce job failed due to "The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am new to hadoop and I am working on Hadoop 2.6.2. I was executing my first wordcount program using the following command:

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.2.jar wordcount input output
```

It shows the following error:

```
17/07/01 07:07:57 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/07/01 07:08:01 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
17/07/01 07:08:01 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
17/07/01 07:08:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1498917081429_0002
17/07/01 07:08:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1498917081429_0002
17/07/01 07:08:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1498917081429_0002/
17/07/01 07:08:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1498917081429_0002
17/07/01 07:08:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1498917081429_0002 running in uber mode : false
17/07/01 07:08:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/07/01 07:08:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1498917081429_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1498917081429_0002_01_000002 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/07/01 07:08:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1498917081429_0002_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1498917081429_0002_01_000003 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/07/01 07:08:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1498917081429_0002_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1498917081429_0002_01_000004 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/07/01 07:08:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1498917081429_0002_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1498917081429_0002_01_000005 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/07/01 07:08:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1498917081429_0002_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1498917081429_0002_01_000006 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/07/01 07:08:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1498917081429_0002_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1498917081429_0002_01_000007 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/07/01 07:08:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
17/07/01 07:08:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1498917081429_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1498917081429_0002_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

17/07/01 07:08:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 3
    Job Counters 
        Other local map tasks=7
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
```

content of configuration files are as follows:

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.permission</name>
            <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/home/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/home/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
            <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.jobtracker</name>
            <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I cant get it, what is happening. Please let me know how could I resolve this.

Comment: Double check if the configuration is being picked from proper location. Seems like wrong classpath issue.

Comment: No, I have checked again. I copied the configuration of class path from [Apache Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/PluggableShuffleAndPluggableSort.html)